# git pull from remote not working

Tags: git, netbeans

I am a new git user. I commonly develop from multiple locations, and then push the changes to a website and central repository. I just started using git as my version manager.

Yesterday I made some significant changes to my website and then pushed the changes to my website and repository where I can see they are in place.

Today from a different site, I attempted to pull these changes to a different local development environment. However no changes have occurred in my local version. I am using netbeans git support. Here's the output:

```
==[IDE]== Dec 5, 2012 9:46:47 AM Pulling...
git pull git@bitbucket.org:****/**.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
==[IDE]== Dec 5, 2012 9:46:59 AM Pulling... finished.
```

After doing this I checked and the latest code changes are not in my current development copy although they are present in both the remote repository and website ( I double checked )

My local copy is NOT a fresh clone. I had hoped to merge the remote changes into my local copy. the first think I did this morning was try to execute the pull.

Can anyone advise me on what to do next to get the latest copy pulled?

thank you,

Bill

Comment: What made you think this is not working if you don't see a reference to merge? Have you double checked that you're missing your latest code after doing a pull? Some more questions: Was it a fresh git clone? If not, did you had a local changes before pull or not? Your question is not clear.

Comment: first: I strongly recommend using the git command line client as a beginner. Try that and tell us what `git pull` and `git branch -va` are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I found the answer. I performed a commit on the local copy ( I guess I had made some changes maybe last time, which I had not committed ), followed by a pull, and this time it gave me the option of merging the 2 commits, and I was able to download the latest changes.

Thanks for your help,

Bill